# Plugin sigue funcionando borrado de wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo un problema con un plugin que se llama sin carrito
https://www.enriquejros.com/plugins/plugin-directo-checkout-sin-carrito/
Lo desactive y luego borre pero sigue funcionando . tambien ya borre el cache y desinstale todos los plugins excepto woocommerce y sigue funcionando.

No encuentro la manera de como hacer que deje de funcionar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui dejo la estructura de archivos del plugin que compre y si necesitan que suba el codigo de algun archivo avisenme.

Solucion: Ya quedo solucionado el plugin al quitarlo no borraba los cambios que hizo al activarse y tuve que borrar manualmente algunas opciones que activo

Se quedo activado la opcion en de redirigir al checkout si seleccionas la opcion de agregar al carrito en woocommerce->productos.

Comment: No estoy muy seguro, sin el código es difícil saber si la función quedo grabada, pero creo que en realidad es un problema de redirección, intenta ingresar desde incognito para verificar si esta generando esa redirección, si aun así sigue sucediendo intenta buscar la parte del código que genera la redirección y postearla aquí, posiblemente se este conectado al filtro woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect.

Comment: Hola  tambien hice la prueba en modo incognito y  hace lo  mismo. No tengo experiencia en moverle a un archivo de wordpress pero lo estuve buscando en el archivo de functions del tema que estoy utilizando y no encontre. A la  mejor lo busque mal.  ¿Me puedes decir en que archivo se tiene que buscar? ¿Necesitas el archivo del plugin?

Comment: Si lo compraste, nada mejor que el soporte de ellos para decirte que pasa no?

Comment: Me comentan que debe haber un problema en mi archivo de functions.php o que algun plugin esta causando problemas.

Comment: Lastimosamente con tan poca informacion no me es posible ayudar, busca el filtro que mencione antes en los archivos del plugin y en los de tu tema, en el archivo functions.php, tambien revisa en las configuraciones de woocommerce, talvez tienes algun otro plugin que tambien realiza esa action

Comment: Yo tu contactaba al desarrollador del plugin y preguntaba tu duda, él es quien mejor te sabrá indicar lo que pasa. Saludos

Comment: Ya quedo solucionado el plugin al quitarlo  no borraba los cambios que hizo al activarse y tuve que borrar manualmente algunas opciones que activo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se quedo activado la opcion en de redirigir al checkout si seleccionas la opcion de agregar al carrito en woocommerce->productos.